# Getting error on creating multidimensional array with new in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, constexpr

```
const int32_t kernel_sizes[1] = {8};

void Create(int id)
{
    float *kernel = new float[1][1][kernel_sizes[id]];
}

Create(0);
```

When I try to create this array, there is a error. The error is:
`Array size is not a constant expression implicit use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function`. What is the reason for this error and how to solve this error?

Comment: float[1][1][kernel_sizes[id]] is a declaration of variable length array that is not a standard C++ feature.

Comment: `new expression` - _"...If type is an array type, all dimensions other than the first must be specified as positive integral constant expression..."_ - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: @VladfromMoscow VLAs are allow in `new` expressions with restrictions.

Comment: `new float[X][Y][Z]` the `X` can be variable, the `Y` and `Z` need to be constant expressions.